# Правильно ли употребление слова "неосвечен", что оно точно обозначает?

Tags: семантика

Можно ли говорить(писать): дом неосвечен,в понимании тёмен?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Парадигма слова ОСВЕТИТЬ](https://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-russian-paradigm-term-42829.htm) Формы "неосвечен" в значении "тёмный" в русском языке нет.

Дом ***не освещён*** - краткое страдательное причастие, *не* пишем раздельно.

Comment: А вообще есть такое употребление? И что оно обозначает?

Comment: Думаю, нет. Видела где-то фразу типа "вопрос не освечен" в значении "не обсуждался, не решался, не публиковался", но и этот вариант неверен.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Могу извлечь из этого слова только *неформально* выраженный смысл:

Не освечен каделябр -

*Не снабжён* он *свечкой*.

Нет свечения. Январь.

Холодно и с печкой.

Comment: Отлично!) Я тоже о такой трактовке думала: не обеспечен, не снабжён свечами. Но это, скорей, окказионализм?

Comment: Это жаргонный способ словообразования (не обилечен, не отоварен и т. п.).

Comment: Так здорово придумано! А кем - не знаю. Неужели вы сами?..

Comment: Это - сам. Но гугл находит такую чью-то строку: Неосвечен свечкой Наш с тобой В тарелках вечер…